# Azure IoT Edge Integration with Lora devices

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, lora, lorawan

I plan to purchase a Lora sensor and a Lora smart valve. I want to integrate those devices with my existing Azure IoT Edge device. I'd like to access the data from the sensor, run it through and IoT Edge ASA Module, and output a command to the smart valve.

1. Is that possible?
2. Is there a Lora Module i could deploy via IoT Hub that would give me access to Lora at the edge?
3. Any recommendations on hardware that will be required, assuming my Edge Device is Azure IoT running Windows IoT?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

[This module](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge-lorawan-starterkit) is an edge LoraWAN implementation to facilitate communication between Lora devices and IoT Hub. It comes with samples and hardware recommendations. With module routing you should be able to route messages to your own ASA module.

As for hardware recommendations, I think that question isn't really something for StackOverflow, but the GitHub page does come with some recommendations for your gateway.

Comment: @Donnie Kerr Do you have further queries? If the above answers your query please accept as answer. As suggested good start is to follow this: [Azure IoT Edge LoRaWAN Starter Kit](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge-lorawan-starterkit)